# CGAL surface_mesh cover example

Tags: compiler-errors, cgal, aabb

On the CGAL webpage you are greeted with this short example:

```
 CGAL::AABB_tree tree(faces(surface_mesh));
```

In all surface_mesh and AABBTree documentation examples this line is not used, so I wonder how I have to configure the AABB traits to make that example possible. My own approach does not compile:

```
    #include <CGAL/AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive.h>
    #include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
    #include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
    #include <CGAL/AABB_triangle_primitive.h>
    #include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
    #include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <list>

    typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> Kernel;
    typedef Kernel::FT FT;
    typedef Kernel::Ray_3 Ray;
    typedef Kernel::Line_3 Line;
    typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;

    typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point> SMesh;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive<SMesh> Primitive;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<Kernel, Primitive> AABB_Mesh_Traits;
    typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<AABB_Mesh_Traits> AABBTree;

    int main( const int argc, const char* argv[] )
    {
        const char* filename = ( argc > 1 ) ? argv[1] : "model.obj";
        std::ifstream input( filename );
        SMesh mesh;
        input >> mesh;
        AABBTree tree( faces( mesh ) );

        Point a( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
        Point b( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
        Ray ray_query( a, b );
        std::cout << tree.number_of_intersected_primitives( ray_query )
           << " intersections(s) with ray query" << std::endl;

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

The compiler error is:

```
 no matching constructor for initialization of 'AABBTree' 
 (aka 'AABB_tree<AABB_traits<Simple_cartesian<double>, 
   AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive<
    Surface_mesh<Point_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> > > > > >')
```

Comment: the website is _lying_ :) It is over simplified and should be `tree(faces(mesh).first, faces(mesh).second, mesh)`.

Comment: Indeed; that single change made it compile. Thank you! Could you @sloriot please add that as a solution? Then I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `tree(faces(mesh).first, faces(mesh).second, mesh)`.

Note that in the [User Manual](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html#aabb_ray_shooting) you find a real example that uses
the complete syntax.  This example comes with the library in the
the directory `examples/AABB_tree`